# Picturebox slider control transparency

Tags: c#, transparency, picturebox, opacity

I've a PictureBox in my form and load a image in it.

I need this PictureBox to change the transparency (opacity, visibilit..etc), because I need the user to see the image behind this PictureBox better, so when he wants, he just drag the control slider and the image starts to turn invisible, step by step, until he finds its ok, lets say 50% transparency.

I added the control slider but, cant find the way to do the rest. I tried the pictureBox.Opacity, pictureBox.Transparency, nothing works.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly! - In Winforms there is no simple way to do this. You will have to modify the alpha of the PBox.Image. See [ColorMatrix for a fast way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-use-a-color-matrix-to-set-alpha-values-in-images).. WPF can do it easily, I believe.

Comment: there is natively no concept of 'behind' - all controls are siblings no matter the location.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: _there is natively no concept of 'behind_ Well at least in Winforms there is nesting and the picturebox is either nested to the form or a tabpage or a groupbox or a panel or some container. so, there is a concept of behind.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In winforms you will have to **modify the alpha** of the `PictureBox.Image`.

To do that in a fast way use a `ColorMatrix`!

Here is an example:

[image]

The trackbar code:

```
Image original = null;

private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (original == null) original = (Bitmap) pictureBox1.Image.Clone();
    pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    pictureBox1.Image = SetAlpha((Bitmap)original, trackBar1.Value);
}
```

To use a [`ColorMatrix`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.colormatrix?view=netframework-4.7) we need this using clause:

```
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
```

Now for the `SetAlpha` function; note that it is basically a clone from the [MS link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-use-a-color-matrix-to-set-alpha-values-in-images)..:

```
static Bitmap SetAlpha(Bitmap bmpIn, int alpha)
{
    Bitmap bmpOut = new Bitmap(bmpIn.Width, bmpIn.Height);
    float a = alpha /  255f;
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmpIn.Width, bmpIn.Height);

    float[][] matrixItems = { 
        new float[] {1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        new float[] {0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
        new float[] {0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
        new float[] {0, 0, 0, a, 0}, 
        new float[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}};

    ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix(matrixItems);

    ImageAttributes imageAtt = new ImageAttributes();
    imageAtt.SetColorMatrix( colorMatrix, ColorMatrixFlag.Default, ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);

    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpOut))
        g.DrawImage(bmpIn, r, r.X, r.Y, r.Width, r.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imageAtt);

    return bmpOut;
}
```

Note the the `ColorMatrix` expects its elements to be be scaling factors with `1` being the identity. The `TrackBar.Value` goes from `0-255`, just like a `Bitmap` **alpha** channel..

Also note that the function creates a **new** `Bitmap`, which may lead to `GDI` **leaking**. Here the `PictureBox` takes care of it, it seems; at least testing it with the taskmanger (*'Details' - turn on GDI-objects column!*) shows no problems :-)

Final note: This will work **if and only if** the `PictureBox` is **nested** in the control 'behind' it! If it merely **overlaps** this will not work!! In my example it sits on a `TabPage`, which is a `Container` and anything you drop on it gets nested inside. It would work the same if I had dropped it onto a `Panel`. But `PictureBoxes` are no containers. So if you want another `PictureBox` to show up behind it, then **you need code** to create the nesting: `pboxTop.Parent = pBoxBackground; pboxTop.Location = Point.Empty;`

Comment: Tnk you very much my friend. I´v tried many days. Im new to C#. This works perfect. Exacly the way i need it. Tnk you very much.